# PHP: creating php browser alike

Tags: php, javascript, browser

Lately i have been working on php-Browser-alike program. The goal of this program is to use this php-browser platform to browse only 'safe' web sites. the capabilities will be to track an adult site and not displaying it.

[image: description]

unfortunately , there are two major problems:

- **Cookies** - user can't log-in their users in different sites while using this platform.
- **Security redirecting** - some sites check the url either in PHP or JS and then redirect to their page.

---

So , simply i though about plain B:

i was thinking about using iFrame and build the whole program in JavaScript and Ajax! but unfortunately , iFrame is super secured and i can't touch anything in it! 
- and there is gone plain B.

**My question is**: is there anything you can think of / advices that can help building PHP/javascript+ajax browser alike program?

Comment: just curious, are you trying to reinvent the wheel? you really want to rewrite a proxy in PHP? there are many free proxy servers with great filtering capabilites out there. Have a look at `squid` for example.

Comment: @Kaii that's wonderful. I've seen the "AirProxy" site and that's exactly what i looking for. you may have a tutorial on how to build one from scratch?

Comment: nope. but google will find it for you

Comment: i posted my comment as an answer so you can accept it :P

Comment: Using a proxy is probably better than a browse-in-browser approach, for the reasons you mention. Just out of interest, what is your use case? There are intriguing questions around where filtering is a good idea at all (perhaps: at a public library -> yes, responding to religious legislation -> no). Just a thought!

Answer (score 1):

For the PHP side you'll need to use curl. You'd probably want to change the html on the server side. Take a look at this [Is there a PHP HTML tag library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196955/is-there-a-php-html-tag-library).

For checking if the site is adult. You should just pass the domain through a database of adult sites.

For javascript I don't know of any pre-made browsers. You'll probably have to block it in yourself, it shouldn't be to hard.

**Update**

basic structure:

- js client makes ajax request to php server using GET or POSt (ex "url=site.com/page/foo.html")
- Php gets url using GET or POST
- php uses curl to get page contents
- php parses through html and changes urls **or** js prevent link press and send href="" to server via ajax (back to top) : [Is it possible to stop redirection to another link page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282307/is-it-possible-to-stop-redirection-to-another-link-page)
- php echos out the page
- javascript places it in display

Answer (score -1):

I know my ans is too late, posting for so that anyone get help. There is a simple solution for creating complete php browser. Here is the link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/